# Alternative way of proving a language is $NP$

Tags: reductions, np

I would like to show a language $A$ is in $NP$.

I can find a TM for $A$, but I wanted to try a different approach and see if it is correct.

Let $B$ be a known problem in $NP$. If I show a polynomial time reduction $A \leq B$, will this imply $A\in NP$?

I believe it will, but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on exactly what kind of reduction you're using.  Assuming that you mean a polynomial-time many-one reduction (also called "mapping reductions") then, yes, if $A$ reduces to $B$ and $B\in\mathrm{NP}$, then $A\in\mathrm{NP}$, also.  This was probably proven to you when you started to study reductions between $\mathrm{NP}$ problems.

If you mean polynomial-time Turing reduction, it's an open problem whether $A\in\mathrm{NP}$.  This corresponds to the question of whether $\mathrm{NP} = \mathrm{P^{NP}}$.

If you don't know what kind of reduction you mean, you should check with your teacher, but it's probably many-one reductions.  Those are the ones that are most commonly used with respect to problems in $\mathrm{NP}$.

Comment: The reduction from the type $x\in A \leftrightarrow f(x)\in B$ is many-to-one?

Comment: @YuraKravitski Yes, that's many-one (so-called because many different values of $x$ may map to the same value $f(x)$).